# Slickgrid: value entered in a cell disappears after moving out of cell

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In a Slickgrid cell, i click and enter a value. Once i move out of this cell using a mouse click the value entered disappears. But if i enter the value in the cell and tab out then the value stays in the cell. I would like to know if this should be manually handled.

OnClick event i am calling

```
grid.updateRow(grid.getDataItem(args.row));
grid.invalidate();
grid.render();
```

Thanks,
Asha

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong, `updateRow()` argument is a row index in the grid but you're passing an item object so that won't work, also if I remember correctly `updateRow` is only used for re-rendering or refreshing a specific row index, it's not for updating the data but more for rendering purposes (perhaps the naming is confusing).

I personally only use the SlickGrid DataView and the functions to call for updating items are different, you can see how to that in this other Stack Overflow answer [Change slickgrid cell data after edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092344/1212166)

If you're using the grid object, as it's written in the other SO answer I referenced earlier, then it would be

```js
grid.invalidateRow(args.row);
data[args.row][grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field] = a.msg;
grid.render();
```

Personally I always use the SlickGrid DataView as it's much more user friendly and comes with a lot more benefit like data grouping and many other functionalities. Again take a look at the other SO answer that I wrote in previous paragraph, that is the correct way to do it

Comment: i have made these changes and yet the behavior is same.

Comment: https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3a-compound-editors.html like in this when you tab out or move to any other cell, the cell where you made the change contains the value. This is not happening in my case

Comment: I have even defaulted a value of cell, when i edit this and move out of this cell the value disappears, please suggest if i am missing something.

Comment: just checking you are using https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki, or one of @ghiscoding    's repos, the mleibman repo is dead. there will be many issues with that repo.